# Why I am asked for the password of a different account when trying to mount a disk?

Tags: mount, password, polkit

I am on Debian 10 Buster.

When using Nautilus (aka Files), I am always asked for my password when trying to mount another HDD. All normal.

A few days ago, I am not asked for my account password anymore, but for another account password.

So, my main account is in the sudo group. I also have a second account named 'guest'. I am not sure what happened so now every time I try to mount a secondary HDD I am asked for the 'Guest' password instead of my main account password (where I am logged in).

Any help?

Thanks

Edit: If anyone want to know more about this, you can also read the answers on this question: [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/642642/what-decides-the-password-account-to-mount-a-disk)

Comment: If you log as guest and umount the disk, does the problem persist?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input. I will try tonight, and let you know

Comment: no, did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok thinking on this, probably “guest” is sudoer.
Remove guest from sudoer:
-sudo visudo and add comment # on guest line
-remove gest from sudo group using sudo usermod -G guest guest ( look at usermod manual to see proper way to keep all groups but sudo, if other groups are present)

Then try again to mount
If admin password asked and you do not remember root password just do sudo su
then passwd and add a new password

Mount the disk with Admin password

Comment: it worked! thanks